# Can I call a class method without calling the overridden method

Tags: dart

I want to call a sibling method **without** calling the overridden method.  Seems like casting *this* to the base class type should work, but doesn't.

Specifically, I want to call Base.bar() from Base.foo() *without* calling any overrides of that method (from Subclass).

```
class Base {
  void foo() {
     print("Base.foo");
     (this as Base).bar(); // I *don't* want to invoke Subclass.bar
  }
  void bar() {
     print("Base.bar");
  }
}

class Subclass extends Base {
  @override
  void bar() {
     print("Subclass.bar");
     super.bar();
  }
}

x = Subclass();
x.foo();

// Expected Output
// Base.foo
// Base.bar

// Actual Output
// Base.foo
// Subclass.bar
// Base.bar
```

Comment: Your best bet might be to make a library-private `_bar()` function that can't be overridden from outside the library (usually that means from other files).

Answer (score 0):

This is a kludge until a **good** answer is given.

```
class Base {
  void foo() {
     print("Base.foo");
     // can't do this => (this as Base).bar();
     Base_bar();
  }

  void Base_bar() {
     print("Base.bar");
  }

  void bar() {
     Base_bar();
  }
}

class Subclass extends Base {
  @override
  void bar() {
     print("Subclass.bar");
     super.bar();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
class Subclass extends Base {
  @override
  void bar() {
     super.bar();
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: No, I'm specifically asking about how to call bar() from foo()